# Assign Existing Mongoose Schema As Datatype

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose

I have some simple Mongoose schema:

```
var usrSchema = new Schema({
      document_state : [documentStateSchema],
      language : {
        type:String,
        required:false    
      },
      currency : {
        type:String,
        required:false    
      },
      main_contact : [mainContactSchema],
      billing_contact : [mainContactSchema],
      admin_contact : [mainContactSchema],
      users : [userSchema], 
      subscriptions : [subscriptionSchema],
      orders: [subscriptionSchema]
    });
```

I need, that *documen_state*  property to be validated to *documentStateSchema* as a single field type, not an array. How could we do that in Mongoose.

Thank you for help.

Comment: remove the square brackets

Comment: It return an error in that case.

Comment: document_state : { type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "WhateverYouCalledYourModel" }

Comment: Dave, than you for replay, but i do not want to manage referencing. I need to handle document_state field to be as a single type of documentStateSchema. Like, for example, document_state:String